# grails - what am I doing wrong with remoteField / fieldValue?

Tags: grails

The following code makes a little table of products:

- column 1 contains the productType name,
- column 2 contains the productType id,
- column 3 contains the quantity the user wants to select,
- and column 4 is a duplicate of column 3 to see what's going on, this time using  id="${i}".

When I display this table, column 2 properly has the id from the productType, as expected.  I then copied and pasted the ${fieldValue(bean ... )} directly into what is used for the id in column 3 (a few times now!) :-)

When I use column 3 to select a product quantity, the 'id' does **not** get passed to the controller (in params).  When I use column 4, the 'id' **does** get passed into the controller in params (as desired/expected).  If I copy what's in column 4 for the id into column 3, column 3 works like column 4.  I can't see the mistake I'm making.  Thanks.

```
<table>
    <g:each in="${productTypeList}" status="i" var="productTypeInstance">
        <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'}">

            <td>${fieldValue(bean: productTypeInstance, field: "name")}</td>

            <td>${fieldValue(bean: productTypeInstance, field: "id")}</td>

            <td><g:remoteField style="font-family:monospace" name="addProduct" action="addProduct"
                               id="${fieldValue(bean: productTypeInstance, field: "id")}" size="2"
                               maxlength="2"/></td>
            <td><g:remoteField style="font-family:monospace" name="addProduct" action="addProduct"
                               id="${i}"  size="2"
                               maxlength="2"/></td>

        </tr>
    </g:each>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh shoot.  It's the quoting on the "id" in the fieldValue function.   IntelliJ used to point out these kinds of errors, but the newest version 11 doesn't seem to.  Depending on an IDE too much can get one into trouble, I guess.  Will have to file a bug with IntelliJ.